# Dropdownlist no show data

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have this dropdownlist and no shows data, I have some errror?

```
 var City = from s in db.City_Office
                         join c in db.City on s.IdCityOffice equals c.IdCity
                         select c;

  ViewBag.IdCityoffice = new SelectList(City, "IdCity", "NameCity");
```

Comment: use break points to see whether data is returned from your query.

Answer (score 0):

First your query may return no data. Secondly, you want to force execution of your query immediately.

Simply 'selecting' doesn't execute it. You need to then use it. Calling ToList() will force execution (or Single() if expecting one)

```
var City = (from s in db.City_Office
                         join c in db.City on s.IdCityOffice equals c.IdCity
                         select c).ToList();
```